Group by grouping result and add group for all results
I want to use a group by expression in my query that creates the groups but also creates a group 'all' where all the instances are added.
The code is just an example to show what I want to do, possible syntax errors are irrelevant.
select (*)
from table
where id in ('a','b','c','d','e','f')
group by case 
when id in ('a','d') then '1'
when id in ('b','e') then '2'
when id in ('c','f') then '3'
when id in ('a','b','c','d','e','f') then 'all'
end

Current result:
1,...
2,...
3,...

Wanted result:
1,...
2,...
3,...
all,...


Look at the documentation of GROUP BY: you have the ROLLUP and the CUBE option.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English (not code or pseudo-code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement; and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment your question is confusing because your pseudo-code is using invalid SQL syntax (SELECT * combined with GROUP BY) and it is unclear exactly what data is going into your query and what the format of the output is expected in.

Use a CASE expression, aggregation and ROLLUP:
SELECT COALESCE(
         CASE 
         WHEN id IN ('a','d') THEN '1'
         WHEN id IN ('b','e') THEN '2'
         WHEN id IN ('c','f') THEN '3'
         END,
         'all'
       ) AS grp,
       SUM(value) AS total_value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  id IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f')
GROUP BY
       ROLLUP(
         CASE 
         WHEN id IN ('a','d') THEN '1'
         WHEN id IN ('b','e') THEN '2'
         WHEN id IN ('c','f') THEN '3'
         END
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 'a', 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  7 UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'e', 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'f', 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  9 UNION ALL
SELECT 'g', 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 23;

Outputs:



GRP
TOTAL_VALUE




1
15


2
9


3
12


all
36



fiddle

I'm not looking to get a sum of them, i need to group the whole instances i just named them '1','2','3' but those are supposed to be names in varchar that contain the results to be used in other elements

@Avseb If you GROUP BY then the columns you are not grouping by need to be aggregated in some way (i.e. SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, LISTAGG). You CANNOT use SELECT lots_of_columns FROM table_name GROUP BY a_few_columns because that is not how the SQL language works (in any SQL dialect).

You have several options, depending on the complexity of your conditions and aggregations, and also on the size of your table, its indexes, other needed joins, etc. This is one simple solution, which will avoid duplicating the CASE.
WITH t AS (
  -- Classification goes here
  SELECT
      CASE 
        WHEN id IN ('a','d') THEN '1'
        WHEN id IN ('b','e') THEN '2'
        WHEN id IN ('c','f') THEN '3'
      AS id,
      table.*
    FROM table
    WHERE id IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f'))
-- Aggregation goes here
SELECT id, SUM (value1), AVG (value2) FROM t GROUP BY id
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'all', SUM (value1), AVG (value2) FROM t

All filtering conditions should be inside the WITH t part. If you're concerned about the double pass over t, analytical functions may solve that.

I'm unable to use 'WITH' in the system I'm working in and I'm not looking to get a sum of them, i need to group the whole instances i just named them '1','2','3' but those are supposed to be names in varchar that contain the results to be used in other elements

@Avseb Oracle supports WITH clauses since at least Oracle 10 (and maybe earlier). If you are not using an Oracle database or are using some pre-processor that modifies the code then you need to tag that in your question so that you get appropriate answers. We cannot effectively help you if you are leave out relevant information from the question.

The WITH is just for avoiding the repetition of the CASE (in the SELECT clause and in the GROUP BY) (or in the double SELECT, which is the core of my idea). You don't really need it.

You can use column names or complex expressions in place of the constants '1', '2', '3'... As @MT0 says, when you GROUP BY you also have to aggregate. Always. I'm using a SUM() aggregation just as an example.
